# Can the Lateran Treaty be regarded as a reference for Separation of Church and State?

Tags: political-theory

Is the Lateran Treaty an example of a strict separation of Church and state?

In my country (Romania) the relationship between the church and the state is a major subject of discussion.  One [legal scholar](https://books.google.ro/books?id=ieSsCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT202&lpg=PT202&dq=does%20romania%20has%20a%20separation%20between%20state%20and%20church&source=bl&ots=eryd5iGHH8&sig=ApKja_MQT2bTcoAZW2je956dHag&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=does%20romania%20has%20a%20separation%20between%20state%20and%20church&f=false) summarized it as:

> In Romania, there is no official Church, but neither is there a
>   strict separation between Church and state….Romania is not a secular
>   state.

This suggests to me that there can be different levels of separation between Church and state. There may be some “strict” separations and some complex arrangements like here in Romania. I would like to find an example of a strict separation.

My research led me to the [Lateran Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateran_Treaty), which formalizes Italy’s recognition of the Holy See as a sovereign entity.  Does this treaty constitute a “strict separation” of Church and state? If so, what makes it strict? If not, why not?

Comment: You tagged this as political theory. Is there a certain kind of theory you are interested in? Otherwise, this is likely to be way too broad.

Comment: @indigochild - yes, I could not find a better tag, since it is a question about a model, not actual politics. I am thinking about a pragmatic way to define the separation between Church and state (something close to the "strict separation model" mentioned in the second reference). Any hint about how to make it less broad is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I think the premise of my comment was off. This basically sounds like, "Does X satisfy the condition of Y" (Does the Lataren Treaty provide a 'strict separation' of church and state)? Provided there is a clear definition of what a "strict separation" is, this would be fine.

Comment: I edited your question. I incorporated your comment and also tried to focus it a bit. Please feel free to roll back my edit or edit it yourself if I missed the mark.

Comment: @indigochild - now it is much better and (hopefully) more answerable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From of the Wikipedia link and the actual treaty, there are two parts of it:

- [The international relationship treaty](http://www.vaticanstate.va/content/dam/vaticanstate/documenti/leggi-e-decreti/Normative-Penali-e-Amministrative/LateranTreaty.pdf)
- [The Concordat](http://www.concordatwatch.eu/topic-39251.834)

#### International Treaty

- Article 1 would be the most troubling, stating:

  > Italy recognizes and reaffirms the principle established in the first Article of the Statute of the Kingdom of 4 March 1848, according to which the Catholic, Apostolic and Roman Religion is the only religion of the State.

  So much for Church-State<sup>1</sup> separation; it lacks practical details (which specific rights the Church gets out of this?) and refers to the [Statuto Albertino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statuto_Albertino) that [also lacks details](http://users.dickinson.edu/~rhyne/232/Four/Statuto.html)

  > Article 1. The Catholic, Apostolic, and Roman religion is the sole religion of the state. All other forms of worship now existing are tolerated in conformity with the law.

  Not the most enticing wording, but vague enough to allow for a claim of Church-State separation.
- The rest of the Treaty *simply does not address the Church-State issue*. It is basically a recognition of Italy of the Vatican as an independent country<sup>2</sup>. It is a *State-State treaty*. Other than allowing travel and residence rights to Vatican "citizens" and some minor points, there are no obligations beyond international laws.

#### Concordat

The Concordat is the true Church-State treaty. And it includes things like:

> Art. 5 No Ecclesiastic may be employed or remain in the employment of an office of the Italian State or any public entity depending from the same without the nihil obstat of the Diocesan ordinary.

So the Church says to the State if he can hire or not priests and the like...

> Art. 20. Bishops before taking possession of their dioceses shall take an oath of fidelity to the head of the State according to the following formula

Art. 34 says that the State recognizes the civil effects of Catholic marriage, and reserves to Catholic tribunals the right to cancel marriages. So (from my reading), no possibility of divorce; because if the Church does not cancel the marriage then the participants are still married in the civil dimension, too.

> Art. 36. Italy, considering the teaching of Christian doctrine according to the form received by Catholic tradition as the foundation and the crown of public instruction, agrees that religious instruction imparted in the public elementary schools shall have a further development in the secondary schools according to a programme to be established by an accord between the Holy See and the State.

Mandatory religious instruction.

> Art. 39. The Universities, the greater and lesser Seminaries, diocesan, inter-diocesan or regional, the academies, the colleges and other Catholic Institutes for Ecclesiastical formation and culture shall continue to depend solely from the Holy See without any interference on the part of the scholastic authority of the Kingdom.

Church control of universities.

The State also reserves some powers for itself (it can protest bishop nominations, bishops must be Italians, etc.)

So, it seems to be far from being a "separation".

I would like to add that it could be argued that any concordat is by definition a breach of the separation of Church and State, since it imposes obligations on each of the parties to the benefit of the other. Of course, not all of the obligations are equally damaging.

---

<sup>1</sup>Wikipedia says that it was cancelled by mutual agreement in 1984.

<sup>2</sup>Although with a few special rules.

Comment: Didn't the Pope promise to not meddle or something like that?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt The Pope dropped the reclamations that he had since Italy took over the Papal States (1870). And certainly, after WWII (messing with Mussolini was a risky affair) the Church did support the Democracia Cristiana party.

Comment: "[allows] a claim of Church-State separation": how? The provision establishes a state religion, which is the opposite of separating church from state.  It also provides for freedom of religion, but freedom of religion is not the same as separation of church and state.

Comment: @phoog both the Treaty article and the one from the Italian Constitution are vague enough to avoid practical consequences *by themselves*. They could be expanded by a lower law to break the Church-State separation, or just be a "symbolic" article (compare with "all the men are created [...] with the right of Liberty" of the USA DoI signed by many slaveholders). So, while certainly "ugly", someone could claim that any breach of State-Church separation is not mandated from such articles (and to make any claims you should have to research the lower level laws).

Comment: @SJuan76 the US declaration of independence has no legal force, which is why people in the US have no legal right to the pursuit of happiness.  Even if lower laws create a sepation of church from state, there's no way you can claim that a document saying "the Catholic, Apostolic, and Roman religion is the sole religion of the state" does so.  I also don't understand your assertion that that statement is vague.  It seems perfectly clear to me.